# IOS and OSX update url or IP blocking?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, macos, wifi

As the title says, I am wondering, does anyone know the url or ip ranges the iPhone and OSX tries to connect to when trying to auto update?

I have searched for how to block updates and such. I have seen nothing on this area of thought. I know one can block updates on IOS from happening on Cell Data. But both IOS and OSX will annoyingly get updates when on wifi.

So my thought is to just block the known addresses they look for at the router/firewall box.

Comment: That doesn't address the question. Connecting to other wifi access points is not an issue as I work from home and never connect to other AP. The main issue is, I am tired of getting bothered by update prompts and I don't want to constantly clear the update file and have it kill my bandwidth by redownloading the packages on each device.

Comment: If I have to I will just create a honeypot of sorts and only have one I device connected with a wireshark on that network to capture it I guess. I was merely curious if someone else did this work.

Comment: The extra things I stated in my comment were not really needed. The question is understandable. Not sure why the agro and down vote based on this. It is a clear concise to the point question. Explaining the "why" in a question is not necessary and usually ends up getting flagged as inciting a conversation instead of a question. I'd appreciate sticking to the rules of the exchange in your votes. Not to your emotions.

Comment: Also, those are not ip ranges. I was unable to find via google of a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has an exhaustive but not completely comprehensive document listing the ports needed for the various features:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944

Sometimes new ports pop up and new destinations - so you'll want to set up monitoring if you have a need to prevent updates that is worth the engineering effort to determine if/when Apple changes their setup.

For updates, you'd need to block port 80 and 443 so it's probably better for you to disable updates rather than try to block them. Apple does change the endpoints and fall back to common ports when specific ports are blocked.

Rather than work on firewall rules, since you'll likely [block other functionality like push notification](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609) and App Store function if you block all Apple IP over those ports, think about configuration profiles to prevent / block updates if you can't just set up devices to not check or apply updates.

Answer (score 1):

1) Go here to block iOS updates coming straight from Apple, current (2017-2018). Caveat: these will block iOS updates **AND** App updates. https://documentation.meraki.com/zGeneral_Administration/Other_Topics/Blocking_or_rate_limiting_iOS_updates

The two sites mentioned are:

- mesu.apple.com
- appldnld.apple.com

2) If your organization also has a Mac hosting its own Apple Software Server, go here (no longer updated as of 4Q2017). Caveat: these are for blocking on-site Apple Software Servers, i.e., a server you maintain on-site to cache Apple updates and distribute them via your own LAN to your own personnel (which cuts down on internet bandwidth usage).
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200149

It lists these:

- swscan.apple.com
- swquery.apple.com
- swdownload.apple.com
- swcdn.apple.com
- swdist.apple.com